# If the integers 1-9 are randomly distributed into three sets of 3 integers, what is the probability that at least one set contains only odd integers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/ThreeGroupsOfThree.shtml has been stated here,

If the integers 1-9 are randomly distributed into three sets of 3 integers, what is the probability that at least one set contains only odd integers?

My approach is that as there are 1, 3 , 5, 7 , 9  = 5 odd numbers, selecting 3 numbers from here would be 5C3  and total number of groups would be 9C3*6C3 so the probability is 5C3/

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways of forming three labeled sets of three numbers from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ is 
$$\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
since we must select three of the nine numbers to be in the first set, three of the remaining six numbers to be in the second set, and all three of the remaining three numbers to be in the third set.

However, if the sets are not labeled, the order in which the sets are selected does not matter.  Hence, the number of ways of forming three sets of three numbers from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ is 
$$\frac{1}{3!}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$

Since there are five odd numbers in the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, there can be at most one set with three odd numbers since $2 \cdot 3 = 6 > 5$. If three odd numbers are selected to be in one of the sets, then the remaining two odd numbers are placed in one set or two different sets.

Three odd numbers in one set and the other two odd numbers in another set:  There are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select the three odd numbers that appear in the same set and $\binom{4}{1}$ to select which even number will be placed in the set with the remaining two odd numbers.  The remaining three even numbers form the third set.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{1}$$
such cases.

Three odd numbers in one set and the other two odd numbers are placed in two different sets:  There are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select the three odd numbers that appear in the same set.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select which two of the four even numbers will be placed in the same set as the smaller of the two remaining odd numbers.  The remaining three numbers form the third set.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}$$
such cases.

Thus, the probability that one of the three sets of three numbers will contain only odd integers is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{4}{1} + \dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dfrac{1}{3!}\dbinom{9}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{3}{3}}$$

Comment: by calculating this we get 3/14 but answer is 5/14, hows that?

Comment: Also why do we care about other set with 2 or 1 odd number as we only need to find probability of a set with all odd numbers.

Comment: You computed the answer incorrectly. $$\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{1} + \binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{2}}{\frac{1}{3!}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}} = \frac{10 \cdot 4 + 10 \cdot 6}{\frac{1}{6} \cdot 84 \cdot 20} = \frac{100}{280} = \frac{5}{14}$$  As for why we care how the odd numbers are distributed, our denominator counts all the ways we can distribute the nine numbers into three sets of three numbers.  Therefore, the numerator must count all the ways we can distribute the nine numbers into three sets of three numbers in such a way that one of those sets consists only of odd numbers.

Comment: For the numerator, what cant we select 5c3 odd numbers in set 1, 6c3 in set 2 and 3c3 in set 3, rather than manually putting them in either one or both of the other sets?

Comment: @Arslán  You could approach it that way, but you would have to take into account the fact that the sets are not labeled.  Since the two sets which do not contain three odd numbers are not distinguished in your approach, you should have $$\frac{1}{2!}\binom{5}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$ favorable cases, which agrees with the count above.